# SSMS Count with HAVING - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, count

I'm trying to count the number of Departments in a database where there are exaclty 6 employees in each Department.

I've written the query below, but it returns the rows with the Departments where there are 6 employees.

But what I'd like is the TOTAL NUMBER of ROWS where each Department has 6 employees.

Does anyone know how I can modify this query to give me a total number, please?

TIA

```
  select count(Department)
        --Department as [Department Name] 
from HumanResources.vEmployeeDepartment
GROUP BY Department
HAVING count(Department) = 6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your query with another `count` statement to count the number of departments returned by the inner query:

```
select COUNT(*) from
(
    select Department as cnt
    from HumanResources.vEmployeeDepartment
    GROUP BY Department
    HAVING count(Department) = 6  
) as t
```